# How to get acknowledge on successful INSERT query in room library using MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room

I am using MVVM architecture in my app. I am facing a problem, i want to get the acknowledgement on successful INSERT **@INSERT** in activity from view model.

**ViewModel Souce code is**

```
 public void insert(UploadApplicationDbModel uploadApplicationDbModel) {
        uploadApplicationRepository.insert(uploadApplicationDbModel);
    }
```

**Repository Source code is**

```
 public void insert(UploadApplicationDbModel uploadApplicationDbModel) {
        new InsertUploadApplication(applicationDao).execute(uploadApplicationDbModel);
    }

private static class InsertUploadApplication extends AsyncTask<UploadApplicationDbModel, Void, Long> {

    private UploadApplicationDao uploadApplicationDao;

    private InsertUploadApplication(UploadApplicationDao uploadApplicationDao) {
        this.uploadApplicationDao = uploadApplicationDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(UploadApplicationDbModel... UploadApplicationDbModel) {
        return uploadApplicationDao.insert(UploadApplicationDbModel[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can check the data.

1. You can manually pull the database and check if the data is inserted or not.
2. You can get the inserted data with a query and check the size
3. You can get numbers of rows affected through your query same as sqlite as shown in below example:

   @Insert
       long insert(Cheese cheese);

   ```
   /**
    * Inserts multiple cheeses into the database
    *
    * @param cheeses An array of new cheeses.
    * @return The row IDs of the newly inserted cheeses.
    */
   @Insert
   long[] insertAll(Cheese[] cheeses);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reverting, but why should I write one more query for getting acknowledge on successful INSERT.? Is there is a way on direct getting return on INSERT function.

Comment: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List<Long> only. 

ideally, you should avoid getting the list from the  Insert. You can do a couple of things 
1. You should check the List<Long> size and if it is > 0 then you should use the same list you don't need to 
write an another query 
2. You can write a query to fetch the list.

Comment: Can we use return type of insert() in Viewmodel. That's used in activity or fragment ?